# Understanding the behavior of Reflect.fields on cpp target

Tags: haxe

can you help me with understanding the behavior of Reflect.fields?

I have this code:

```
var obj:Dynamic={arr:["aaa","bbb","ccc"]};
trace(Reflect.fields(obj));
trace(Reflect.fields(obj.arr));
```

JS target output:

```
[arr]
[0,1,2]
```

CPP target output (Android NDK):

```
[arr]
[]
```

Why CPP target didn't return [0,1,2]?

Comment: Disclaimer: I have no real knowledge of the cpp target. My guess: 0, 1 & 2 aren't real fields on this array. In javascript, they are because in javascript all is pretty much an object in which `o[key]` means something like `o.key`, so an array gets a "pseudo-field" for each item.  CPP is right here: those are not fields.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the [API documentation](https://api.haxe.org/Reflect.html#fields) on `Reflect.fields()`

> This method is only guaranteed to work on anonymous structures.

So the behavior on array is not specified.